# Filter Boto3 "client.describe_volumes" response

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto3

I'm trying to extract data from some EBS volumes using Boto3, specifically: 'Device', 'InstanceId' and 'AvailabilityZone'.

This is my code:

```
import boto3

AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=AWS_REGION)


volume_id_list = ['vol-02e15c9d70exxxxx', 'vol-0bbcb1b0e98xxxxx'] 


for vol_id in volume_id_list:

    response = client.describe_volumes(
        VolumeIds=[
        vol_id,
        ],
    )

    print(response)
```

I'm getting the following response, although the data is there I'm not being able to extract it because of the format:

```
{'Volumes': [{'Attachments': [{'AttachTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 23, 18, 18, 9, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Device': '/dev/xvda', 'InstanceId': 'i-xxxxxxxxxxx', 'State': 'attached', 'VolumeId': 'vol-02e15c9xxxxxxx', 'DeleteOnTermination': True}], 'AvailabilityZone': 'us-east-1a', 'CreateTime': datetime.datetime(2022, 11, 23, 18, 18, 9, 713000, tzinfo=tzutc()), 'Encrypted': False, 'Size': 8, 'SnapshotId': 'snap-xxxxxxxxxxx', 'State': 'in-use', 'VolumeId': 'vol-xxxxxxxxxxx', 'Iops': 100, 'VolumeType': 'gp2', 'MultiAttachEnabled': False}], 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': 'xxxxxxx-eb66-4be9-a2c6-0xxxxxxxxx', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'x-amzn-requestid': 'xxxxxx-eb66-4be9-a2c6-xxxxxxxx', 'cache-control': 'no-cache, no-store', 'strict-transport-security': 'max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains', 'content-type': 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8', 'content-length': '1201', 'date': 'Wed, 07 Dec 2022 17:07:50 GMT', 'server': 'AmazonEC2'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}
```

Is there a way to filter the response so I can only receive 'Device', 'InstanceId' and 'AvailabilityZone'?

Thanks in advance

Comment: hey dumb me from the past, this is how you get that data: 

`device = response['Volumes'][0]['Attachments'][0]['Device']`
`instance = response['Volumes'][0]['Attachments'][0]['InstanceId']`
`az = response['Volumes'][0]['AvailabilityZone']`
`print(device)`
`print(instance)`
`print(az)`

Comment: You are welcome to add your own Answer.

Answer (score 1):

Sure @John Rotenstein, here is the complete answer:

This is how I got the data I needed:

```
import boto3

AWS_REGION = "us-east-1"
client = boto3.client('ec2', region_name=AWS_REGION)


volume_id_list = ['vol-02e15c9d70exxxxx', 'vol-0bbcb1b0e98xxxxx'] 


for vol_id in volume_id_list:

    response = client.describe_volumes(
        VolumeIds=[
        vol_id,
        ],
    )

    device = response['Volumes'][0]['Attachments'][0]['Device']
    instance = response['Volumes'][0]['Attachments'][0]['InstanceId']
    az = response['Volumes'][0]['AvailabilityZone']

    print(device)
    print(instance)
    print(az)
```